# React-native ScrollView scrolls sometimes in wrong direction

Tags: react-native, gesture, scrollviewer, react-native-flatlist

Weird problem with react-native ScrollView/Flatlist. When i'm scrolling down or up the content scrolls sometimes the opposite direction. It's mostly when im scrolling with one hand. I recorded a youtube video of this problem.

i also tried to use the ScrollView class of react-native-gesture-handler without any luck. Is this a common behavior?

[youtube link (visualization of the problem)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MU2oSHtXag)

phone used: Huawei p20

To to reconstruct use the following

```
react-native init TestProject
paste code below in App.js
react-native run-android (on real device) 
scroll with one hand
```

Paste this code in App.js to reconstruct this issue.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Animated,
} from "react-native";


const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: "Press Cmd+R to reload,\n" + "Cmd+D or shake for dev menu",
  android:
    "Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n" +
    "Shake or press menu button for dev menu"
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)
  };

  render() {
    let { scrollY } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
        <ScrollView
          style={{
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            width: "100%",
            height: "90%",
            paddingBottom: "5%"
          }}
          bounces={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        >
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text> Test </Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    margin: 2,
    height: 40,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width - 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#e5e5e5"
  },
  container: {
    //  marginTop: 50,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  contentContainer: {
    paddingVertical: 0
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: I just copied your code in my project, it works fine for me in my Moto G5 and simulator. Also as code point of view, it looks perfect.

Comment: thanks for trying out. i cant make it work very strange...

Comment: why Huawei has weird side effects in React Native apps?

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution for this issue? I have a Oneplus 5 and is having the same behaviour.

Comment: @kabus did you solve this? I am seeing this on Samsung A33